# Debug sampler Non-GUI

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to get the debug sampler results while running jmeter in non-gui mode? More simply I am looking for a way to log all the variable substitutions that happen while the test is run. I tried enabling and disabling debug logs for the available packages, but am still not able to get the substitutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the options:

1. [sample_variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property. For instance if you need to see values for variables `foo` and `bar` add the next line to *user.properties* file which lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation:

   ```
   sample_variables=foo,bar
   ```

   and aforementioned variables values will be added as separate columns to .jtl results file. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of working with them
2. You can print something to *jmeter.log* file via [__log()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__log) or [__logn()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__logn) functions

Comment: Listing all the variables would not be optimal, well atleast not for my case. Thanks though for pointing me to the log functions. That helped.